# metalLB vs ingress vs (nodeport or cluster ip) in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

I want to deploy kubernetes in a **non-cloud environment.**

I know MetalLB is an L2 load balancer and ingress is an L7 load balancer and nodeport can load balance in L4, but the question is in production (expecting 1 million requests) how should I use them?

Is it necessary to have all of them?

nodeport can load balance between pods that are on different nodes so it seems that using MetalLB that also load balances between nodes is useless.
How can you explain it?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you deploing it on premises? I would use all of them in production, and use metallb in mode BGP, where it divides the on going traffic among the nodes. Metallb divides the traffic between the physical nodes, Ingress finds the appropriate service, and NodePort find the pod in the cluster. They are all necessary for best practices. If you are on cloud providers go for a LB launched there. It can scale accordingly to demand.

Comment: are you sure i need all of them?

Comment: a nodeport can find pod in diffrent node so i think metalLB is useless.
how can you explain it for me.thanks

Comment: It is better to divide the income traffic among the nodes than to route all the traffic to just one machine. Also it is also better to not be attached to fixed ip, being better to use DNS. In case of any failure, the IP address will change, but the DNS will not. So it is better to use DNS´s than a node IP. I can use the same idea to justify the use of ingress, instead of using nly a node port service.

Comment: by metalLB all traffic comes to one worker and then divide to other worker node

Comment: If you use layer2  approach. The BGP approach will route to all the nodes.

Comment: Antway you would not be coupled to a fixed node IP and port, which can die over time or change

Comment: yes. One for directing traffic for nodes (MetalLB) and ingress to redirect the traffic for each service.

Comment: in metalLB in baremetal i can not get ip.do you face this ?

Comment: Nope. I am able to get an IP from internal network (172.xxx.xxx.xxx). Is the IP that you are requesting available. I guess metalLB acquires this IP through DHCP.

Comment: are you in BGP mode?

Comment: do you have physical router?
or you have virual router?
i use virtual router in document i can access the loadbalancer ip from inside kubernetes but it is inaccessible from out side

Comment: I am using layer2 mode. I need to change to BGP in the future. I am not part of the network team, so not sure if they are talking to a physical router or not. Try layer 2 for now. Just to see if it works.

Comment: yes layer 2 work fine but i want to loadbalance between worker nodes.

Comment: is there any error presented? I think metal lb pod shows all process of getting a new IP. Perhaps there is something useful there.

Comment: no every thing is fine but it is not accessible from other ubuntu those are not kubernetes

Comment: @LeandroDonizettiSoares, there is a lot of useful clarification in the comment exchange. It'd be really nice and useful if you could update your answer with those.

Comment: @LeandroDonizettiSoares L2 will also route to all nodes as well but they must meet the criteria of having an application advertised on the IP and the speaker responding to requests on said node. Speakers are deployed on each node as they are daemonsets